Insights on non-commutative operator families on rational functions satisfying the braid relation
I am studying the article "Symmetrization operators in polynomial rings" by A. Lascoux and M.-P. Schützenberger (MSN). Specifically, I am trying to prove the following claim involving operators defined on the ring of rational functions $\mathbb{C}(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, where the variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are permuted by the simple transpositions $s_i = (i, i+1)$, for $i = 1, 2$.
Define linear operators $D_i$, $i = 1, 2$, as:
$$
D_i = P_i + Q_i s_i,
$$
where
$$ P_i(x_i, x_{i+1}) = \frac{(\alpha x_i + \beta)(\gamma x_{i+1} + \delta)}{x_i - x_{i+1}}, 
\quad Q_i = \eta - P_i,
$$
and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \eta \in \mathbb{C}$.
Given:

$D_1 D_2 D_1 = D_2 D_1 D_2$,
$D_1$ is invertible, and $P_1 \neq 0$.

Claim:
We must have $\Delta := \alpha \delta - \beta \gamma \neq 0$, $\eta \neq 0$, and $\eta \neq \Delta$.
Brute-force computation quickly becomes infeasible, and the authors hint that a deeper approach using non-commutative operator calculus associated with reflection groups (E. Gutkin) might be necessary. However, this technique seems challenging to navigate without more intuition or intermediate insights.
Can anyone provide comments or suggestions on how to approach such computations? Specifically, I am seeking ideas, conceptual guidance, or references that could shed light on a more efficient approach to this problem.

I added what I think is the (English) title of the article, and a link to MSN relay station.  If that is not correct, then could you give more detail about the reference?

I'd replace the $Q_i$ by its definition and use the combination $\partial_i = (x_i - x_{i+1})^{-1},(1-s_i)$. This is the divided difference, which itself obeys the braid relations, and some quadratic relation (for just $\partial_i$). It preserves the space of polynomials, and has a simple action on monomials.
